# Detecting empty lines and absence of text in a UITextView in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uitextview

I have created a UITextView programmatically , and added a placeholder  like so:

```
    //textView
    textView.frame = CGRectMake(viewSize.width * 0.05, contentView.frame.height - viewSize.width * 0.05, viewSize.width - viewSize.width * 0.05 * 2, -viewSize.height * 0.220833)
    self.textView.delegate = self
    self.textView.text = "Agregue una descripción..."
    self.textView.textColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
    self.textView.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionType.No
    self.textView.layer.cornerRadius = 6
    self.view.addSubview(textView)
```

and in the delegate functions:

```
func textViewDidBeginEditing(textView: UITextView) {

    if textView.textColor == UIColor.lightGrayColor() {
        textView.text = ""
        textView.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    }
}


func textViewDidEndEditing(textView: UITextView) {
    if textView.text.isEmpty {

        textView.text = "Agregue una descripción..."
        textView.textColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
    }
}
```

I have also tried to check string text to nil:

```
if textView.text == nil
```

And like this:

```
if textView.text == ""
```

None did detected the empty lines, and even the nil comparison was not detecting the absence of text after adding and deleting some chars.

So when the user enters text there is no problem, and when the user deletes all the text the placeholder comes back, but if you add a line or more without any text, the comparison to empty is not true, i need a way to detect that i have no text and also the lines added do not have text, because the newly introduced in Swift `.isEmpty` is not detecting empty lines added, nor any of the other comparison did.

How can i detect empty lines in my String?

Comment: What is _your_ definition of an "empty line", exactly?

Comment: "if you add a line or more without any text, the comparison to empty is not true" Correct, because the text is _not_ empty. A space character, or a return character, _is text_.

Comment: @matt when you just hit _return_ but did not add any character to that new line

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ask yourself whether the text is composed of only characters from the NSCharacterSet `whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet` (or whatever characters constitute emptiness in your mind - perhaps what you are after is `newlineCharacterSet`). The easiest way is to take its `invertedSet` and call `rangeOfCharacterFromSet` - if the result is `{NSNotFound, 0}` (Swift `nil`), this text *is* composed only of whitespace characters.

```
extension String {
    var isBlank : Bool {
        let s = self
        let cset = NSCharacterSet.newlineCharacterSet().invertedSet
        let r = s.rangeOfCharacterFromSet(cset)
        let ok = s.isEmpty || r == nil
        return ok
    }
}

"howdy".isBlank // false
"".isBlank // true
"\n\n".isBlank // true
```

Comment: why would you go the extra mile and define cset/r instead of direclty invoking ".stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet()"?

Comment: @longbow If you have a different answer, give it as a different answer! I'll upvote it.

Comment: @matt it worked, i created a new Swift file, and added code, now i will keep it for further use as an extension. thanks.

Comment: @matt I was just curious if there is good reason to do so, not doubting your way of solving the problem.

Answer (score 3):

"quick and dirty" version of the code matt posted, without extending String:

```
func textViewDidEndEditing(textView: UITextView) {

    let myAwesomeDescription = textView.text.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSe‌​t())

    if myAwesomeDescription == "" {

        //user did not modify empty box or text only consisted of space/newline characters, reset placeholder text and placeholder textColor
        textView.text = "Agregue una descripción..."
        textView.textColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()

    } else {

    //textView holds a valid string, do stuff

    }

}
```

What does myAwesomeDescription do? We refer to a great [NSHipster article](http://nshipster.com/nscharacterset/) for that:

> **Stripping Whitespace**
>
> NSString -stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet: is a
> method you should know by heart. It's most often passed NSCharacterSet
> +whitespaceCharacterSet or +whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet in order to remove the leading and trailing whitespace of string input.
>
> It's important to note that this method only strips the first and last
> contiguous sequences of characters in the specified set.

That being said, this not only helps us dealing with Strings that have unnecessary leading or following spaces/newlines, but also with "empty" which in most definitions will mean that the String is just spaces/newlines only.

Comment: it does perfectly on my end, the only thing that i just found was that xcode has problems finding the character set if you just copy/paste the above, so i changed it to the long version

Comment: the only thing i added was "NSCharacterSet" (please see the edit history for that), which XCode was not able to resolve by itself just having ".whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSe‌​t()" - please go try and delete NSCharacterSet as soon as it resolves to a class function and you will see that the code before is valid Swift code that will compile!

Comment: As you are again accusing me of nonsense, let me ask again "Did you even try?" http://imgur.com/Dn0aAGy - I can also make an animated gif of actually live typing it if you want.

Comment: Okay, I see the problem. You've got some invisible null characters before the "t" in `set`.